# Does Bitcoin mining benefit at all from having more video memory?

Tags: mining-setup

Example: I am mining on a Windows computer with guiminer on an onboard gpu. Will assigning more memory to the IGP improve its performance while mining?

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely. SHA-256 uses very little memory, so while I don't know a lot about GPU mining code, I would doubt that additional GPU memory would be used at all - I can't think what it would be used for.

But if you want to know for sure - since this is a simple BIOS option, why not just try it both ways and see?

Answer (score 0):

GPU Mining is dead. It's been overtaken by ASICs which are many orders of magnitude more efficient. There is no point in even trying.

Comment: Thanks, but I already know that and it doesn't answer my question.